# Can we have a form with fields from different pages in multipage document in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a multi page document in jquery mobile. 
Page 1 has a link that redirects me to page 2. Page 2 has a button that will submit the request to the server.
Is it possible to create a form that have form fields spread in both page 1 and page2 and when  I submit the form the fields in both the pages get submitted.
Does multi page document in jquery mobile support this? Or is there any other way to do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The long page forms can be spread over two pages in the same html as shown in the following code.

```
<body>
    <form action="/m/processOrder.php" method="post">
        <div data-role="page" id="delivery">
            <?php $headerTitle = "Deliver To"; ?>
            <?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
            <div data-role="content">
                <h2>Where will we be delivering?</h2>
                <!—-form elements go here -->
                <p>
                    <div class="ui-grid-a">
                        <div class="ui-block-a"><a data-role="button" href="index.php">Cancel</a></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><a data-role="button" href="#payment">Continue</a></div>
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="payment">
            <?php $headerTitle = "Payment"; ?>
            <?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
            <div data-role="content">
                <h2>Please enter payment information</h2>
                <!-—form elements go here -->
                <p>
                    <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a"><a data-role="button" data-theme="d" href="index.php">Cancel</a></div>
                        <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="submit"data-theme="b" value="Submit"/></div>
                    </div>
                </p>
            </div>
            <?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
            </div>
    </form>
<body>
```

Multiple `data-role="page"` can exist in single dom.
From official jqm documentation

> A HTML document may start with a single "page" and the Ajax
>   navigation system will load additional pages on demand into the DOM as
>   users navigate around. Alternatively, a HTML document can be built
>   with multiple "pages" inside it and the framework will transition
>   between these local views with no need to request content from the
>   server.

here is the [link](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/pages/) to documentaion.

The code snippet from **Creating Mobile Apps with jQuery Mobile** by **Shane Gliser**